# Why does my mini iPad still won't display with my media query?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I have this media query for my mobile display

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), only screen and (max-device-width: 760px)
```

But other phone device works fine whenever when I turn landscape view in mobile. But iphone 6 and Mini iPad won't display when landscape view. What exactly do I need to add to let the device work and display?

Comment: Try this for mobiles; @ media only screen (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 479px), only screen (max-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 479px) and for ipads; @ media only screen (min-width:480px) and (max-width: 480px), only screen (max-device-width: 767px) and (max-device-width: 767px)

Comment: @ media should be @media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iphone 6 and iPad have an horizontal resolution bigger than `760px` so both media queries are false and whatever css rule you have inside will not be applied.

You need a "tablet" rule for the landscape mode e.g. with `1024px` or even higher breakpoint